# Symlink all directories whose names contain word (Windows Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, symlink

I have Directory A, which contains a bunch of subdirectories, and empty Directory B. I would like to create a .bat file that symlinks all of the subdirectories inside Directory A whose names contain "april" (only the top-level ones) into Directory B. Is this possible?

What I have so far is:

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Updating Directories...
if exist "C:\path\to\directory\a" (
    echo Updating Directories...
    set "dira=C:\path\to\directory\a"
    set "dirb=C:\path\to\directory\b"
    for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "!dira!"`) do (mklink /d "!dirb!\%%f" "!dira!\%%f")
    title Symlinks Created^^!
    echo Done^^!
    pause
) else (
    echo Cannot find Parent Directory.
    pause
)
```

This works, but it symlinks all of the subdirectories inside Directory A into Directory B. Is there a way I can, for example, search for top-level directories whose names contain "april," return the list, and then only symlink those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CatCat I was able to figure it out. Here's what's now working, for posterity's sake:

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Updating Directories...
if exist "!userprofile!\path\to\directory\a" (
    echo Updating Directories...
    set "dira=!userprofile!\path\to\directory\a"
    set "dirb=!userprofile!\path\to\directory\b"
    for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "!dira!\*april*.*"`) do (mklink /d "!dirb!\%%f" "!dira!\%%f")
    title Symlinks Created^^!
    echo Done^^!
    pause
) else (
    echo Cannot find Parent Directory.
    pause
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want a batch file. Just type the command.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /ad "%userprofile%\desktop\*u*.*"') Do mklink /d "%userprofile%\desktop\b\%~nxA" "%A%
```

This create a link in a folder called B on the desktop (so create it first) for any folder on the desktop that contains the letter u in the name. See `dir /?`.

Note in Windows (NT family) the wildcard operators are regular expressions unlike Dos.

`?*net*.*` shows all files that contain net, but don't begin with net.

Comment: This didn't really answer my question, but it helped me figure it out and I've managed to get it working. Thanks, I'll vote up at least!

Comment: Code needs to be tested. I'm not replicating your environment (even, if unlikely, there is enough info to). Hence a line of code that requires you to make one folder on your desktop to see how to solve your problem - use wildcards in the `dir` statement.